# Using shared element transition with edittext

Tags: android, shared-element-transition

Im trying to use shared element transition

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
       edit_activity.setTransitionName(getString(R.string.activity_text_trans));
       edit_wbs.setTransitionName(getString(R.string.activity_mixed_trans));
       Pair<View, String> pair1 = Pair.create(edit_activity, edit_activity.getTransitionName());
       Pair<View, String> pair2 = Pair.create(edit_contractor, edit_contractor.getTransitionName());
       Pair<View, String> pair3 = Pair.create(edit_labour_used, edit_labour_used.getTransitionName());
       ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.
                                            makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, pair1, pair2, pair3);
        startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
    }
```

But im getting the following error

> Error:(469, 75) error: incompatible types: Pair
>   cannot be converted to Pair

I have tried changing the edittext to View. 
If i change the type, Im unable to use the setText and getText properties of edittext.

How can i be able to sort this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try in pair a static transition name like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailsActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(DetailsActivity.EXTRA_CONTACT, contact);
Pair<View, String> p1 = Pair.create((View)ivProfile, "profile");
Pair<View, String> p2 = Pair.create(vPalette, "palette");
Pair<View, String> p3 = Pair.create((View)tvName, "text");
ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.
    makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, p1, p2, p3);
startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
```